# comparing two unsorted files

Tags: bash, shell

I have two tab separated files (please see the examples below):

#### File 1

```
Java    RAJ
PERL    ALEX
PYTHON  MAurice
```

(and so on)

#### File 2

```
ALEX    3.4
SAM     8.9
PEPPER  9.0
```

Now, if for instance say ALEX is also found in file 2 (it is not for sure that ALEX will be found) I should have a third file looking like this:

```
PERL ALEX 3.4
```

The code should check for all the values in column 2 of file 1 in file2.

Any suggestions for a bash script?

Comment: "One liner bash script" ... like [this one here](http://bash.org/?464385)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `join` for that. First you need to sort according to join field though:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort +1 -2 file1) <(sort +0 -1 file2)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {val[$1]=$2; next} $2 in val {print $0, val[$2]}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is a one-liner with PERL also ok?
Works without sorting..
Assuming your files are called f1 and f2..

```
perl -e 'open(F1, shift); open(F2, shift); $ls = $/;undef $/;$f2 = <F2>;$/ = $ls; while(<F1>) { ($t1, $t2) = $_ =~ /^(\w+)\s+(\w+)$/; if($t1) { ($t3) = $f2 =~ /^$t2\s+(.+)$/m; print "$t1 $t2 $t3 \n" if ($t3); } }' f1 f2
```

With f1:

```
Java RAJ

PERL ALEX

PYTHON Maurice
```

And f2:

```
ALEX 3.4
SAM 8.9
PEPPER 9.0
```

Results in:

```
PERL ALEX 3.4
```

Comment: Is that really good practice? It looks like a very hard to read one line.

Comment: @YGomez: you are supposed to use that, not read that. Perl is write only language :)

Answer (score 1):

You received excellent answers using *join* and *awk*, so I thought I's post a pure bash-one:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A name2prog
declare -A name2num

while read a b; do name2prog[$b]=$a; done < file1
while read a b; do name2num[$a]=$b; done < file2

for i in "${!name2num[@]}"
do
    if  [[ ${name2prog[$i]} ]]; then
        echo ${name2prog[$i]} $i ${name2num[$i]}
    fi
done
```

outputs:

```
$ ./try.sh
PERL ALEX 3.4
```