# Using goto LABEL for comparing two files

Tags: perl, goto

I am unable to get desired output.
Please help to correct my errors.

**file1**

```
A  
B  
C 
D  
E
F
```

**file2**

```
A  
D  
C
```

**Desired Output**  *(if found print '1' at relative position in larger file and if not print '0')*

1
0
1
1
0
0

**code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open(FH,$file);
@q=<FH>;
open(FH1,$file2);
@d=<FH1>;
open(OUT,">out.txt");

foreach $i(@q) {
    foreach $j(@d) {
        if ($i eq $j) {
            $id=1 ;
            goto LABEL;
        } elsif ($i ne $j) {
            $id=1;
            goto LABEL;
        }
    }
}
print OUT "1\t";
LABEL:
print OUT "0\t";
}

close FH;
close FH1;
close OUT;
```

**note: actual files are much much larger and *contain uneven number of elements*.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were looking for

```
for $q (@q) {
    my $found = 0;
    for $d (@d) {
        if ($q eq $d) {
            $found = 1;
            goto LABEL;
        }
    }

    LABEL: print "$found\n";
}
```

The above is better written as follows:

```
for $q (@q) {
    my $found = 0;
    for $d (@d) {
        if ($q eq $d) {
            $found = 1;
            last;
        }
    }

    print "$found\n";
}
```

But those solutions perform poorly. You can avoid iterating over `@d` repeatedly by using a hash.

```
my %d = map { $_ => 1 } @d;
for $q (@q) {
    print $d{$q} ? "1" : "0", "\n";
}
```

Comment: It was perfect, let us see how much time it takes on my original files.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature 'say';

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1';
open my $fh2, '<', 'file2';

say <$fh1> eq <$fh2> ? '1' : '0'
  until eof $fh1 or eof $fh2;
```

Notes:

- `use strict; use warnings;` to maintain sanity
- `autodie` to take care of failed file `open`s
- Lexical filehandles are preferred to bareword filehandles
- `say` for syntactic sugar to automatically append a newline at the end of every 1 or 0
- Diamond operator to read in each filehandle line-by-line
- `eq` to string-compare the two lines
- Ternary operator (`COND ? TRUE : FALSE`) to decide whether to print 1 or 0
- `until` is a negated `while`
- `eof` to tell the loop when either of the two filehandles has been exhausted

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. He doesn't want to compare line for line, he wants to know if the items in @q are in @d.

Comment: @ikegami : The OP has changed the question since this answer was posted (the question title still says "comparing two files"). Sad part is that they never even notified of the change via the comment box.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said don't use `LABEL`. And to be honest you don't need perl for that, because [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) and [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) do the job (may be you need to sort the files first):

```
join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -o 2.1  file1.txt file2.txt | sed "s/[^0]/1/g"
```

May be you need to sort your files first - in this case have a look at this post: [comparing to unsorted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696321/comparing-two-unsorted-files).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest `LABEL` is not your friend - don't do that. For me it sounds more like a job for the [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join). But if you want to solve it using Perl I would try the following:

If the input files are sorted (otherwise you can use [sort](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort) to achieve that) compare them line by line and print the result:

```
while ($line_from_f1 = <F1>)
{
    $line_from_f2=<F2>;
    if ($line_from_f1 eq $line_from_f2)
    {
        print "1\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "0\n";
    }
}
```

Shorter version (untested):

```
while (<F1>)
{
    print ($_ eq <F2>)."\n"; 
}
```

Note: These versions compare the files line by line - if a line is missing in the middle it does not work properly.

Comment: shorter version is working but for smaller file as F1 not larger.

Comment: yes you are right - I would prefer `join` (but that's not Perl, which was asked here)

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. He doesn't want to compare line for line, he wants to know if the items in @q are in @d.

Comment: Oops, apparently the OP changed his question since you posted. Sorry, can't unvote.

Comment: @ikegami no problem such things happen AND you were right ...so I posted a  second answer which takes your comment into account